# Why is the "wrong" expression of an ifelse macro evaluated anyway?

Tags: if-statement, m4

I wrote a small m4 script (`test.m4`) for testing purposes:

```
define(`test', `ifelse(`$#', `1', `$1', test(shift($@)))')
test(`arg1', `arg2')
```

and ran it with `m4 test.m4 -t test -de`<sup>1</sup>. The output was

```
m4trace: -1- test -> ifelse(`2', `1', `arg1', test(shift(`arg1',`arg2')))
m4trace: -2- test -> ifelse(`1', `1', `arg2', test(shift(`arg2')))
m4trace: -3- test -> ifelse(`1', `1', `', test(shift(`')))
m4trace: -4- test -> ifelse(`1', `1', `', test(shift(`')))
.
.
.
```

until execution was aborted due to an exceeded recursion limit. I wondered why this was so because actually `1` and `1` should compare equal and the `if else` macro should evaluate to `` `' ``.

However, I had the innovative idea to put the [`[not-equal]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Ifelse) into quotation marks, so the macro looked like this:

```
define(`test', `ifelse(`$#', `1', `$1', `test(shift($@))')')
test(`arg1', `arg2')
```

and voilà, it worked like a charm (i.e., `arg2` was printed out along with a leading newline).
The output (with the same invocation parameters):

```
NL
m4trace: -1- test -> ifelse(`2', `1', `arg1', `test(shift(`arg1',`arg2'))')
m4trace: -1- test -> ifelse(`1', `1', `arg2', `test(shift(`arg2'))')
arg2
```

<sub>(`NL` stands for "newline").</sub>

My conclusion: even though the two strings to compare are, in fact, equal, the preprocessor evaluates the [`[not-equal]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Ifelse) branch nevertheless.

Does this have any specific purpose? IMO, it's just unintuitive. Or am I missing something?

---

<sup>1</sup> `-t test` turns debug tracing for the macro `test` on. `-de` adds the definition of an invoked macro to the debugging output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the expressions are equal (besides quotes), their time of execution differs (owing to quotes).

In the first case `test` macro gets executed DURING macrosubstitution of the parent's `test`. So you experience a recursion: test inside test inside test and so on.

The second case makes the expression executed AFTERWARDS. So you don't have recursion. test after test after test.

[This behaviour is very well described in the manual.](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html)

Section "16.3 Other incompatibilities":

> In cases like this one, an interdiction for a macro to hold its own name would be a useless limitation. Of course, this leaves more
>   rope for the GNU m4 user to hang himself!